# How to register support for text file to be opened by other apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, controller, uidocumentinteraction

How to register support for text file to be opened by other apps, having support for text file in iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my application please refer the link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rahul Mathur, your answer is justifying my needs.